# how to increase height and width of a input text box in pug/jade

Tags: pug

```
input(type="text" id="body" name="body" rows="100" cols="100" maxlength="300" tabindex="100" value="" rows="100" cols="100"  autocomplete="off" required)
```

I have done this but isn't working...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<input type="text" />` elements are single-line only input fields. The [Mozilla Web Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/text) describes them as:

> A single-line text field. Line-breaks are
>   automatically removed from the input value.

To have an input that accepts multiple lines, and in order use the `rows` and `cols` attributes, you need to use a [`<textarea>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/textarea) element instead of an `<input>`.

Comment: I verified this

textarea( id="test" name="test" maxlength="300" tabindex="100" value="" rows="100" cols="100"  autocomplete="off" required)